# How to solve Chinese character display in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, nscharacterset

after Mysql installation , I create a table and add some records like this

```
create table score (
    student_id int,
    subject varchar(10),
    subject_score int
);

insert into score values (001,'数学',50),(002,'数学',60),(003,'数学',70);
```

and the result is

```
mysql> select * from score;
+------------+---------+---------------+
| student_id | subject | subject_score |
+------------+---------+---------------+
|          1 | ??      |            50 |
|          2 | ??      |            60 |
|          3 | ??      |            70 |
+------------+---------+---------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

and then I changed "character set"

```
mysql> alter table score character set utf8;
mysql> alter table score modify subject varchar(10) character set utf8;
mysql> set character_set_server=utf8;


mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character_set%';
+--------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                                                   |
+--------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                                                    |
| character_set_connection | utf8                                                    |
| character_set_database   | utf8                                                    |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                                                  |
| character_set_results    | utf8                                                    |
| character_set_server     | utf8                                                    |
| character_set_system     | utf8                                                    |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/local/mysql-5.5.47-linux2.6-x86_64/share/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

and my table struture is

```
mysql> show create table score\G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: score
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `score` (
  `student_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `subject` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `subject_score` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I think everything is fine but when I query my table, Chinese character still cannot display correctly

```
mysql> select * from score;
+------------+---------+---------------+
| student_id | subject | subject_score |
+------------+---------+---------------+
|          1 | ??      |            50 |
|          2 | ??      |            60 |
|          3 | ??      |            70 |
+------------+---------+---------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

but when I insert the same records again , new record is fine!

```
mysql> insert into score values (001,'数学',50),(002,'数学',60),(003,'数学',70);
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from score;
+------------+---------+---------------+
| student_id | subject | subject_score |
+------------+---------+---------------+
|          1 | ??      |            50 |
|          2 | ??      |            60 |
|          3 | ??      |            70 |
|          1 | 数学    |            50 |
|          2 | 数学    |            60 |
|          3 | 数学    |            70 |
+------------+---------+-------
```

how to save my old records? I need somebody help and thank you very much

Comment: This link https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-asian-sets.html may help you

Comment: `how to save my old records?` - they already damaged on insert, multibyte content was thrown away and just saved as `?`-s...

Comment: @ankhzet Oh my god !! thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Use UTF-8 when you create table.

> create table table_name () CHARACTER SET = utf8;

Use UTF-8 when you insert to table

> set username utf8; INSERT INTO table_name (ABC,VAL);